# Multi-Site Active Directory Sync

Tags: active-directory

I have created 4 Active Directory Domain Controllers both in different locations. One is in Delhi and Another one in Mumbai.

Delhi has 2 domain controllers Primary(DDC01) and Secondary(DDC02).

Mumbai has 2 domain controllers Primary(MDC01) and Secondary(MDC02).

Both have different networks and I can take the RDP of both Domain controllers from different locations.

Now I want to connect all 4 Domain Controllers so they can replicate the data and policies.

I saw this can be done through Active Directory Site and Services.

I Added Subnet's of Both Sites in Mumbai DC i.e. MDC01

I created Sites such as Mumbai-HO and Delhi-BO in MDC01 it got replicated to MDC02.

I could see MDC01 and MDC02 but I cannot see any of the DDC01 or DDC02 showing there.

Am I missing something?

Just FYI... DDC01 and DDC02 are having different gateways due to some reason.

Comment: Are they in the same domain or did you create two separate domains?  If they’re in the same domain the , barring networking issues (and DNS), they should all replicate with each other by default.  Setting up subnets and sites just informs AD of the network topology so it can be more efficient with its replication and so that clients know which DC is “local” to them.

Answer (score 0):

There is a single Domain at both locations.

I tried Telnet with the below ports on both locations and only 138 port is not working and getting connection failed.

UDP Port 88 for Kerberos authentication
UDP and TCP Port 135 for domain controllers-to-domain controller and client to domain controller operations.
TCP port 139 and UDP 138 for File Replication Service between domain controllers.
UDP Port 389 for LDAP to handle normal queries from client computers to the domain controllers.
TCP and UDP Port 445 for File Replication Service
TCP and UDP Port 464 for Kerberos Password Change
TCP ports 3268 and 3269 for Global Catalog from client to domain controller.
TCP and UDP Port 53 for DNS from client to domain controller and domain controller to the domain controller.

In Active Directory Sites, I cannot see all the Domain Controllers. At Delhi, I can only see DDC01 and DDC02 and similar is the case with Mumbai.

I renamed the Default Site names at both Sites but still the same issue.